# Segmentation fault with shared pointers

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

What's wrong with this code (I minimized my whole code)? I can't figure out why `pu.useIt();` causes a segmentation fault.

```
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Person {
    private:
    shared_ptr<string> name;

    public:
    void setName(shared_ptr<string> name) {
        this->name = name;
    }

    shared_ptr<string> getName() {
        return name;
    }
};

class PersonCreator {
    shared_ptr<Person> person;

    public:
    void createAmy() {
        shared_ptr<string> amysName = make_shared<string>("amy");
        person->setName(amysName);
    }
};

class PersonUser {
    public:
    void useIt() {
        PersonCreator pc;
        pc.createAmy();
    }
};

int main()
{
    PersonUser pu;
    pu.useIt();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize `person`, now it is empty, default ctor of shared_ptr means that it points to nullptr:

```
void createAmy() {
        shared_ptr<string> amysName = make_shared<string>("amy");
        person = std::make_shared<Person>();  // added
        person->setName(amysName);
    }
```

Comment: Is `default ctor of shared_ptr` an extra information, you get? I only get return code 139

Comment: @Ben I don't understand, can you clarify your question? You got 139 exit code because there was not `Person` instance pointed by *person*, so `setName` was called for nullptr pointer. After this modification is your app still crashing?

Comment: Actually my minimization is wrong... Your answer is totally correct for my question.